# How to do a recursive template match in xslt

Tags: xslt, xhtml, xsl-fo

I have a text with html inside it, im trying to render the html present in it. But im facing problem when there are nested tags inside.

For ex: In my XML

```
<section>
<p><u><em><b>Hello</b></em></u></p>
</section>
```

And in my XSLT i have like

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="section/b">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
</fo:inline>
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:when test="section/u">
<fo:inline text-decoration="underline"><xsl:apply- 
templats select="*|text()"/>
</fo:inline>
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:when test="section/em">
<fo:inline font-style="italic"><xsl:apply- 
templats select="*|text()"/>
</fo:inline>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="section"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But it is not getting this rendered in my PDF.

Is there a way to match tags or any ways to do recursive template matching, or any other solutions?

Any idea/ suggestions?

Comment: What would be the expected result in your example, with all 3 styles present? -- Hint: `test="section/b"` fails because `b` is not a child of `section`; try testing for `section//b` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple templates, they will apply recursively:

```
  <xsl:template match="b">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="u">
    <fo:inline text-decoration="underline">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="em">
    <fo:inline font-style="italic">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I.e., replace the `xsl:choose` in the question with `<xsl:apply-templates />` and include the templates from @Lucero elsewhere in the stylesheet. Also, the `select` attributes are redundant in these templates since the default will select the element and text node children anyway. See, e.g., https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Applying-Template-Rules: "In the absence of a `select` attribute, the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction processes all of the children of the current node, including text nodes."

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Its working like a charm. Thanks a lot @Lucero and Tony Graham !!!